# Elegant methods to handle the definite Integral of $\sqrt{\tan x}$ from limits $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2} $ are wanted!

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

After finding the indefinite [integral](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-integral-of-sqrt-tan-x-1/answer/Lai-Johnny?ch=17&oid=229121919&share=bbb0ceb7&srid=CCOmo&target_type=answer)

$$\int \sqrt{\tan x}\, dx,$$
I can easily evaluate the definite integral by putting limits as below:

$$\int _0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{\tan x}\, dx=\left[\dfrac { 1 } { \sqrt { 2 } } \tan ^ { - 1 } \left( \dfrac { \tan x - 1 } { \sqrt { 2 \tan x } } \right)+ \dfrac { 1 } { 2 \sqrt { 2 } } \ln \left| \dfrac { \tan x - \sqrt { 2 \tan x } + 1 } { \tan x + \sqrt { 2 \tan x } + 1 }\right |\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt2}  $$

However, I believe that  there are many other ***elegant*** methods to evaluate it. Looking forwards to seeing more from you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The antiderivative is not too complex.

Let
$$\sqrt {\tan(x)}=t \implies x=\tan ^{-1}\left(t^2\right)\implies dx=\frac{2 t}{t^4+1}\,dt$$
$$I=\int \sqrt {\tan(x)}\,dx=2\int \frac{ t^2}{t^4+1}\,dt=2 \int \dfrac{t^2}{\left(t^2-\sqrt{2}t+1\right)\left(t^2+\sqrt{2}t+1\right)}\,dt$$
$$I=\frac 1{2^\frac{3}{2}}\int\left(\dfrac{t}{t^2-\sqrt{2}t+1}-\dfrac{t}{t^2+\sqrt{2}t+1}\right)\,dt$$

For the first one
$$\dfrac{t}{t^2-\sqrt{2}t+1}=\frac 12 \frac{2t-\sqrt 2}{t^2-\sqrt{2}t+1}+ \frac 1{\sqrt 2}\dfrac{1}{t^2-\sqrt{2}t+1}$$
$$\int\dfrac{t}{t^2-\sqrt{2}t+1}\,dt=\frac{1}{2} \log \left(t^2-\sqrt{2} t+1\right)+\frac 1{\sqrt 2}\int\dfrac{1}{t^2-\sqrt{2}t+1}\,dt$$ For the last written integral, complete the square and use the traditional change of variable to get an $\tan^{-1}(.)$.

Do the same with the second integral and you should end with

$$I=\dfrac{\ln\left(t^2-\sqrt{2}t+1\right)-\ln\left(t^2+\sqrt{2}t+1\right)+2\left(\arctan\left(\sqrt{2}t+1\right)+\arctan\left(\sqrt{2}t-1\right)\right)}{2^\frac{3}{2}}+C$$

Recombine the logarithms and the arctangents.

Using now the bounds
$$\int_0^\frac\pi2\sqrt{\tan (x)}\, dx=2\int_0^\infty \frac{ t^2}{t^4+1}\,dt=\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: We can also restate this as$$\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{t^2dt}{t^4+1}=\frac12\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{u^{1/2}du}{u^2+1}=\sum_\pm\left.\pm\pi i\frac{z^{1/2}}{z\pm i}\right|_{z=\pm i}=\sum_\pm\frac{\pi(1\pm i)}{2\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$$by the residue theorem.

Answer (score 1):

If you know Beta and Gamma functions, you can show$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\tan^{2s-1}xdx=\frac12\operatorname{B}(s,\,1-s)=\frac12\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)=\frac{\pi}{2}\csc\pi s.$$In this case you want $s=\frac34$, so the integral is $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: I m not much familiar with the calculations of beta and gamma functions , will you please suggest a read for the properties of beta functions.

Comment: @Abhiraj.M See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) & [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) (maybe also [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler%27s_Reflection_Formula) & [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76399/one-line-proof-of-the-eulers-reflection-formula)).

Comment: Thanks a lot .Really helpful.